# How to set a foreign key in an association that is further away?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an application where a `user` can have many `people` which can have many `projects` which can have many `invoices`.

in my `invoice`controller I have this action:

```
def create
  project = current_user.projects.find(params[:invoice][:project_id])    
  @invoice = project.invoices.build(params[:invoice])
  if @invoice.save
    flash[:success] = "Invoice created."
    redirect_to invoices_path
  else
    render :action => "new"
  end
end
```

The problem is that it throws an error whenever there is no `project_id`.

I understand that and tried something like this instead...

```
@invoice = current_user.people.projects.invoices.build(params[:invoice])
```

...but I get an `undefined method projects` error then.

I just want to make sure that a new `invoice` will automatically associated with the correct `user` and that nobody can tamper with it.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: What do your ActiveRecord associations regarding `people` look like?

Comment: If you can do `current_user.projects.find` can't you also do `current_user.projects.build`? Just do that if there's no project to look up.

Comment: @gregates: Thanks for your help. I am not sure I understand what you mean. You mean I should build a new `project` from within my `invoice` controller if no project exists?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to accomplish what you want. I tested this in my console, so it should work. I messed up the person/people pluralization, but you should get the gist. I gave dummy attributes to the models for testing purposes.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :persons

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :person_name, :user_id
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :projects
  has_many :people_invoices
  has_many :invoices, through: :people_invoices

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :person_id, :project_name, :user_i
  belongs_to :person
  has_many :invoices

class PeopleInvoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :invoice_id, :person_id
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :invoice

class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :invoice_amount, :person_id
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :people_invoice
  has_many :persons, through: :people_invoices
```

I gave some dummy attributes to each of the models, which you can see in the attr_accessible fields above.

In my console, I tried:

```
@user = User.new(name: "User")
@person = @user.persons.create(person_name: "Employee")
@project = @person.projects.create(project_name: "foo")
@invoice = @project.invoices.create(invoice_amount: 25)
@person_invoice = @person.people_invoices.create(invoice_id:1)
```

With your associations this way, then you can call:

```
@user = User.find(4)
<User id: 4, name: "User", created_at: "2012-10-19 20:18:28", updated_at: "2012-10-19 20:18:28"> 
@user.persons
=> [#<Person id: 5, user_id: 4, person_name: "Employee", created_at: "2012-10-19 20:19:00", updated_at: "2012-10-19 20:19:00">]
@person.invoices
[#<Invoice id: 1, project_id: 2, invoice_amount: 25, created_at: "2012-10-19 19:33:10", updated_at: "2012-10-19 19:33:10">]
```

Because of the associations, you should be able to find invoices corresponding to projects and persons and trace them back to specific users, too. Since the relationships are has_many, you'll get arrays returned to you (notice the brackets in the last two console outputs). You'll then have to cycle through them in a block to see or access specific values.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your help! I just wonder why the new model `PeopleInvoice` is necessary. Could you explain that to me?

Comment: Sure. I used it sort of as a "bridge." Since you wanted people associated to invoices, but not necessarily via Projects, PeopleInvoices is a way to People and Invoices directly while still allowing them to operate independently. It's essentially a JOIN table that has the keys needed to make the association directly. You could probably use a HABTM relationship, but this is more flexible than that (see section 2.8 here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has_many-through-and-has_and_belongs_to_many).

Answer (score -1):

You should use `through`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :projects
    has_many :invoices, through: projects
end

class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :projects
    has_one :user, through: projects
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :invoice
end
```

Comment: I am actually! But `through` can only link three associations as far as I know...? I have four...

Comment: Ok, I think you have obfuscated your relations a bit.  If an invoice can only have 1 user, you should build a direct relationship between users and invoices.